# How do you extend a (Choquet) capacity to a product of sets?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, capacities

Let $F$ be a set. A paving $\mathcal{F}$ on $F$ is a subfamiliy of $2^F$ containing $\emptyset$. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a paving on a set $F$ which is closed under finite unions and finite intersections. A Choquet capacity on $F$ is an extended real valued set function $I$ on $2^F$ with the following properties.

(a) $I$ is monotone, that is, if $A\subseteq B\subseteq F$ then $I(A)\leq I(B)$.

(b) If $\langle A_n\rangle$ is an increasing sequence of subsets of $F$, then $I\big(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\big)=\sup_{n}I(A_n)$.

(c) If $\langle A_n\rangle$ is a decreasing sequence of elements of $\mathcal{F}$, then $I\big(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\big)=\inf_n I(A_n)$.

A subset $A$ of $F$ is called capacitable if $$I(A)=\sup\{I(B):B\in \mathcal{F}_\delta \text{ and } B\subseteq A\}.$$

Questions:

(1) What's the smallest paving on $F$ which makes all the singletons capacitable? Taking $\mathcal{F}=2^F$ certainly works.

(2) Is there a way to extend these definitions to $F\times F$?

Note: I'm not worried a lot about the ''...extended real valued...'' in the above definition. I'm okay with the capacity taking just the nonnegative finite values.

My main reference is Dellacherie and Meyer's Probability and Potential. I'd really appreciate it if you could refer me to some other sources as well. Thanks.